# Missing LVM tools in Debian 10

Tags: debian, lvm

I have a *Debian 10* system which uses an encrypted `LVM2`.

Currently I have a 10G `/var` partition that is not big enough for my daily usage of `docker`, so I decided to resize it.

To my surprise, I have **no tool to manage LVM** installed, nor available in my repositories!  Plus the documentation in *Debian* wiki is outdated.

```
root@almanzora:~# pvchange
bash: pvchange: command not found
root@almanzora:~# pvck
bash: pvck: command not found
root@almanzora:~# pvcreate
bash: pvcreate: command not found
root@almanzora:~# pvdisplay
bash: pvdisplay: command not found
root@almanzora:~# pvmove
bash: pvmove: command not found
root@almanzora:~# pvs
bash: pvs: command not found
root@almanzora:~# pvscan
bash: pvscan: command not found
root@almanzora:~#
```

How can I handle now my `LVM` without the tools and not "breaking Debian" by installing old packages from previous versions?

Comment: Debian 10 certainly delivers [LVM2 packages](https://packages.debian.org/buster/lvm2). I am not sure why they would be missing from your repositories, maybe show the output of `apt update` or let us know if you are using an architecture that may not have LVM2 packages built for it.

Comment: When the system is already using LVM, the idea of LVM tools not being installed does not make sense unless the tools have been actively uninstalled since the last boot. So the reason almost certainly had to be something else. And that `su` change has surprised quite a few Debian users... including myself :)   (Comment replaced by a real answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that in older versions of Debian the `su` command came from the old `shadow` source package, but Debian 10's `su` comes from `util-linux` source code and has different semantics.

Depending on how exactly you're switching to root, you might now be getting `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` omitted from your `PATH`, which would explain the shell not finding the LVM tools.

Debian 10.x does not include any */sbin paths by default. Solve this issue with "export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH".

In this particular case, switching to root with `su -` (instead of `su`) adds the appropriate directories to the `PATH`.t

Comment: export /usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH generates an error. export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin will do the job. great explanation. thanks

Comment: @hotips Thanks, typo fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with a recently installed Debian 10.3
Just install lvm2 package:

`apt install lvm2`

or `sudo apt install lvm2` if not from root.

That did the trick for me.